# Large delay (10 seconds) occurs sometimes between PostQueuedCompletionStatus and GetQueuedCompletionStatus

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, io, iocp

This is related to a previous post [Recv Buffer for IO Completion port always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991721/recv-buffer-for-io-completion-port-always-empty)

I've added a PostQueuedCompletionStatus to my code to allow me to trigger messages in the IOCP worker threads. This works most of the time, but every once in a while I will see 10 second delay between the PostQueuedCompletionStatus and the GetQueuedCompletionStatus triggering.

Timing wise I've checked that the GetQueuedCompletionStatus is waiting and I'm not off in another part of the worker thread. I have also tried increasing the worker thread's priority and class even into the realtime thread priority ranges, This didn't seem to have any noticeable effect.

Any ideas as to why I get a 10 second delay on the queue sometimes?(really hoping to get this down to less than a second)

networkhandlerthread.ccp

```
#include "NetworkHandlerThread.h"

// Worker thread, processes IOCP messages.
DWORD ServerWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    HANDLE CompletionPort = (HANDLE)lpParam;
    DWORD BytesTransferred = 0;
    OVERLAPPED* lpOverlapped = NULL;
    LPCONNECTED_SOCKET_DATA ConnectedSocketData = NULL;
    LPPER_IO_OPERATION_DATA PerIoData = NULL;
    DWORD Flags = 0;
    WSABUF* DataBuf;
    DWORD RecvBytes = 0;
    Type1MessageParser Type1MsgParser;
    Type2MessageParser Type2MsgParser;
    int DestinationAddress = 0;
    bool IsType1 = false;

    while (TRUE)//run forever
    {
        //Check for new message
        if (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(CompletionPort, &BytesTransferred, (PULONG_PTR)&ConnectedSocketData, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&PerIoData, INFINITE) == 0)
        {
            DWORD Err = GetLastError();
            if (Err != WAIT_TIMEOUT)
            {
                printf("GetQueuedCompletionStatus() failed with error %d\n", Err);

                if (closesocket(ConnectedSocketData->Socket) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    printf("closesocket() failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    return 0;
                }

                GlobalFree(ConnectedSocketData);
            }
            continue;
        }


        //We have a message, determine if it's something we receaved or something we should send.
        if (PerIoData->OperationType == OPERATION_TYPE_RECV)
        {
            /// there is code here that processes the recvs now
            /// but i cut it out to save space. didn't seem to have anything to do with the 
            /// issue
            ConnectedSocketData; //this is comming in good and has data
            PerIoData->Buffer; // this is empty (pointer is good, but no data)
        }
        else if (PerIoData->OperationType == OPERATION_TYPE_SEND)
        {
            ///same as above, there is code here to process sends, but cut to save space.
        }
    }
};


//Thread for handling Listener sockets and Accepting connections
DWORD ListenThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    LPLISTEN_SOCKET_DATA pSocketData = (LPLISTEN_SOCKET_DATA)(lpParam);
    WSANETWORKEVENTS NetworkEvents;
    DWORD dwRet;
    SOCKADDR_IN NewSockAddr;
    SOCKET      NewSocket;
    int         nLen;

    while (true) //run forever
    {
        //Wait for event
        dwRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1,
            &(pSocketData->hAcceptEvent),
            false,
            100,
            false);

        //Nothing happened, back to top
        if (dwRet == WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
            continue;

        //We got a event, find out which one.
        int nRet = WSAEnumNetworkEvents(pSocketData->Socket,
            pSocketData->hAcceptEvent,
            &NetworkEvents);
        if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            wprintf(L"WSAEnumNetworkEvents error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

        //We got a Accept event
        if (NetworkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT)
        {
            //Check for errors
            if (NetworkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_ACCEPT_BIT] == 0)
            {

                // Accept new connection
                nLen = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
                NewSocket = WSAAccept(pSocketData->Socket,
                    (LPSOCKADDR)&NewSockAddr,
                    &nLen, NULL, NULL);
                if (NewSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    wprintf(L"accept() error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    break;
                }

                wprintf(L"Accepted Connection %ld", NewSockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);

                //Set new connection as TCP connection, No Delay
                //const char chOpt = 1;
                //int nErr = setsockopt(NewSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &chOpt, sizeof(char));
                //if (nErr == -1)
                //{
                //    wprintf(L"setsockopt() error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                //    break;
                //}


                LPCONNECTED_SOCKET_DATA ConnectedSocketData = new CONNECTED_SOCKET_DATA;

                ZeroMemory(ConnectedSocketData, sizeof(CONNECTED_SOCKET_DATA));

                ConnectedSocketData->Socket = NewSocket;
                ConnectedSocketData->Port = pSocketData->Port;
                ConnectedSocketData->IOCP = pSocketData->IOCP;
                ConnectedSocketData->CfgHandle = pSocketData->CfgHandle;
                ConnectedSocketData->ForwardMessager = pSocketData->ForwardMessager;

                //Add the new socket to the completion port, message from the socker will be queued up for proccessing by worker threads.
                if (CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)NewSocket, pSocketData->IOCP, (DWORD_PTR)ConnectedSocketData, 0) == NULL)
                {
                    wprintf(L"CreateIOCompletionPort error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    delete ConnectedSocketData;
                    ConnectedSocketData = NULL;
                    closesocket(NewSocket);
                    break;
                }

                //Set the PerIOData, will be used at completion time
                LPPER_IO_OPERATION_DATA PerIoData;
                PerIoData = (LPPER_IO_OPERATION_DATA)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, sizeof(PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA));

                ZeroMemory(&(PerIoData->overlapped), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
                PerIoData->BufferLen = 0;
                PerIoData->OperationType = OPERATION_TYPE_RECV;
                DWORD RecvBytes = 0;
                DWORD Flags = 0;
                PerIoData->Buffer.buf = PerIoData->cBuffer;
                PerIoData->Buffer.len = DATA_BUFSIZE;


                //Kick off the first Recv request for the Socket, will be handled by the completion Queue.
                if (WSARecv(NewSocket, &(PerIoData->Buffer), 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, &(PerIoData->overlapped), NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    wprintf(L"WSARecv error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"Unknown network event error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


NetworkHandlerThread::NetworkHandlerThread()
{
    m_CompletionPort = 0;
    m_hListenThread = 0;
}

NetworkHandlerThread::~NetworkHandlerThread()
{

}

void NetworkHandlerThread::StartNetworkHandler()
{
    int iResult = 0;
    SYSTEM_INFO SystemInfo;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    //Start WSA
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup() failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return;
    }

    //Start Completion Port
    m_CompletionPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (m_CompletionPort != NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"Completion Port Created\n");
    }

    //Get # of system processors
    GetSystemInfo(&SystemInfo);

    //create Worker Threads for each processor.
    for (i = 0; i < SystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors * THREADS_PER_PROCESSOR; i++)
    {
        HANDLE ThreadHandle;

        // Create a server worker thread, and pass the
        // completion port to the thread. 
        ThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServerWorkerThread, m_CompletionPort, 0, NULL);

        // Close the thread handle
        if (ThreadHandle != NULL)
        {
            CloseHandle(ThreadHandle);
        }
    }
}

void NetworkHandlerThread::AddListenThread(int Port,
    ConfigHandler* pConfigHandle,
    void* ForwardHandle)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN InternetAddr;
    int iResult = 0;
    LPLISTEN_SOCKET_DATA pListenSocketData = new LISTEN_SOCKET_DATA;

    if (pListenSocketData == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Create the listener Socket
    pListenSocketData->Socket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
    if (pListenSocketData->Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Create a Event to handle Socket Accepts
    pListenSocketData->hAcceptEvent = WSACreateEvent();
    if (pListenSocketData->hAcceptEvent == WSA_INVALID_EVENT)
    {
        wprintf(L"WSACreateEvent() error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(pListenSocketData->Socket);
        return;
    }

    // Set the Event to Trigger on FD_ACCEPT (this occurs on socket connection attempts)
    int nRet = WSAEventSelect(pListenSocketData->Socket,
        pListenSocketData->hAcceptEvent,
        FD_ACCEPT);
    if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"WSAAsyncSelect() error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(pListenSocketData->Socket);
        return;
    }

    //Assign the Port Number
    InternetAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InternetAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    InternetAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    pListenSocketData->Port = Port;
    pListenSocketData->IOCP = m_CompletionPort;
    pListenSocketData->CfgHandle = pConfigHandle;
    pListenSocketData->ForwardMessager = ForwardHandle;

    //Bind the Socket to the Port
    iResult = ::bind((pListenSocketData->Socket), (sockaddr*)&InternetAddr, sizeof(InternetAddr));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"bind function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(pListenSocketData->Socket);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    //Listen for incoming connection requests.
    if (listen(pListenSocketData->Socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"listen function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(pListenSocketData->Socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    wprintf(L"Listening on %ld", Port);

    m_hListenThread = (HANDLE)CreateThread(NULL,                // Security
        0,                  // Stack size - use default
        ListenThread,  // Thread fn entry point
        (void*)pListenSocketData, //Listen Socket Data
        0,                  // Init flag
        NULL);  // Thread address
}
```

NetworkHandlerThread.h

```
#pragma once
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ForwardMessageHandler.h"
#include "ConfigHandler.h"
#include "Type1MessageParser.h"
#include "Type2Message-Parser.h"
#include "ThreadUtilities.h"

#define DATA_BUFSIZE 8192
#define THREADS_PER_PROCESSOR 2

class NetworkHandlerThread
{
public:
    WSADATA wsaData;
    HANDLE m_CompletionPort;
    HANDLE m_hListenThread;

public:
    NetworkHandlerThread();
    ~NetworkHandlerThread();

    void StartNetworkHandler();

    void AddListenThread(int Port,
        ConfigHandler* pConfigHandle,
        void* ForwardHandle);
};
```

ThreadUtilities.h

```
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include "ConfigHandler.h"


using namespace std;

#define DATA_BUFSIZE 8192
#define THREADS_PER_PROCESSOR 2

typedef struct _THREAD_MESSAGE
{
    mutex cmd_mtx;
    string command;
} THREAD_MESSAGE, * LPTHREAD_MESSAGE;

typedef struct _LISTEN_SOCKET_DATA
{
    SOCKET Socket;
    int    Port;
    HANDLE hAcceptEvent;
    HANDLE IOCP;
    VOID* ForwardMessager;
    ConfigHandler* CfgHandle;
    // Other information useful to be associated with the handle
} LISTEN_SOCKET_DATA, * LPLISTEN_SOCKET_DATA;

typedef struct _CONNECTED_SOCKET_DATA
{
    SOCKET Socket;
    int Port;
    HANDLE IOCP;
    VOID* ForwardMessager;
    ConfigHandler* CfgHandle;
} CONNECTED_SOCKET_DATA, * LPCONNECTED_SOCKET_DATA;

#define OPERATION_TYPE_UNKNOWN      0
#define OPERATION_TYPE_SEND         1
#define OPERATION_TYPE_RECV         2
typedef struct PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA
{
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    WSABUF Buffer;
    char cBuffer[DATA_BUFSIZE];
    int BufferLen;
    int OperationType;
    string PacketName;
};

#define LPPER_IO_OPERATION_DATA PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA
```

DataRecver.cpp
The CompletionPort and ConnectedSocketData are sent over in the worker thread RECV, stored off and used when SendMessage is called.

```
void SendMessage(string DataRecved, string PacketName, HANDLE CompletionPort,
                 LPCONNECTED_SOCKET_DATA ConnectedSocketData)
{
   WSABUF TempBuf;
   LPPER_IO_OPERATION_DATA PerIOOperationData = new PER_IO_OPERATION_DATA;
   ZeroMemory(&(PerIOOperationData->overlapped), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
   PerIOOperationData->BufferLen = DataRecved.length();
   PerIOOperationData->OperationType = OPERATION_TYPE_SEND;
   DataRecved.copy(PerIOOperationData->cBuffer, DataRecved.length(), 0);
   PacketName.copy(PerIOOperationData->PacketName, PacketName.length(), 0);

   PostQueuedCompletionStatus(CompletionPort, DataRecved.length(), reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR> 
      (ConnectedSocketData), &(PerIOOperationData->overlapped));
}
```

Comment: Are there other threads currently working on events on this same completion port? You may have just reached its configured concurrency limit. IO completion ports have a mechanism to avoid dispatching a new job if there are too many current jobs in progress to avoid having more jobs in progress than the CPU has cores. You may be inadvertently misusing this mechanism to delay starting new jobs even when current jobs aren't CPU bound. Read the [concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) documentation.

Comment: So I printed out the number of Processor/Threads at startup, currently have 1 thread per processor and 40 processors. Currently starting out slow with about 5 messages occurring back to back in 2 second intervals on the RECV side and the same number on the SEND side that occur about 200 ms after the RECVs. Processes everything fine for a good long while (about 2000 K messages), then hits the 10 second delay issue. repeats at about the same interval ~2000k messages. 
Don't think this amount of messages would tie things up ( messages are around 12 bytes long give or take a couple bytes).

Comment: is there maybe a release/finished processing mechanism for the IOCP I'm missing somewhere that could be causing this?

Comment: Do the threads that service the completion port do anything else? You should create threads that only service a single completion port for their entire life to keep things simpler. That way, when they're done processing, they block in GQCS immediately.

Comment: What do you set the number of concurrent threads to when you create the completion port?

Comment: I have tried 0 and also the number of processors (40), both should in theory do the same thing, and I have seen no change in behavior, I also tried double the number of worker threads to 2x times the number of processors from 1x times the number of processors, same behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234869/discussion-between-user2076574-and-david-schwartz).

Comment: @user2076574 - Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: Just noticed this post. I do have a solution now, ended up getting some help from the Microsoft forum on this. I'll strip down the solution and post it below in a few days.

Comment: @user2076574, I seem to be having the exact same problem and would love to hear the solution! Please share!